# Xcode beta 10 quits when adding a texture to node

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, textures, skspritenode

Xcode 10 beta 6 on MacOs Mojave  keeps quitting when trying to add texture to my GameScene Node

Comment: Can you please share the code (`texture`) you are tring to add? Do you get any error?

Comment: the texure i am trying to add is a simple png image downloaded from pixabay

Comment: Is it crashing?  As in unexpectedly quitting?

Comment: yes the app just quits by itself

Comment: well a box tells us why it just quits then, you would need to share that.